# swift dynamic numbers of line

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

i work with ios 8 swift an have a textfield into a table cell.

if i put in this textfield a short text, i have no problems.

but is there a long text, the end of the this will cut, like this:

**"This is the Exmaple of ..."**

how can i set dynamic a second line in to my textfield, if the text will be to long for it?

i do not have any code because i dont know how i can solve this situation.

Comment: uitextfields are limited to 1 line of text

Comment: okay, is there an option, to let automatic slide to end and start to show all of text?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but what I would do is rethink your use of a UITextField and use a UITextView. The problem with needing to scroll by swiping from right to left to see what you wrote creates a pretty terrible user experience unless of course you have a specific use case where the user will have a better experience by needing to scroll from right to left to see what they wrote.

Comment: ok, i try it with an texview, but i can only scroll vertical. but i have to scroll horizontal, i would like to have only one line if this possible

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` can contains only one line of text. The component you need is the `UITextView`.

Comment: ok, i try it with an texview, but i can only scroll vertical. but i have to scroll horizontal, i would like to have only one line if this possible

Comment: Textviews can scroll horizontal. What do you mean with "I would like to have only one line"?